# Is there a way of finding uID of a specific application?

Tags: c#, winapi, icons, tray, shell32

I am trying to catch the `uID` variable from the [NOTIFYICONDATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataa) struct, used in `Shell_NotifyIcon` function (shellapi.h). I got the `hWnd` of the process window and `hIcon` the handle of the icon.

The application does not provide a way to hide the system tray icon.

I am looking forward to delete the icon by executing a code using [Shell_NotifyIconA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyicona) `NIM_DELETE` to hide the specific icon of a specific proccess I don't have the access to it's source code.

What I was trying to do:

- I got the hWnd by using user32.dll findWindow function
- I got the hIcon by sending a request to hWnd for receving back the hIcon value

Answer (score 0):

Windows allows the user to hide icons they don't care about, there is no reason to resort to hacks on WinXP and later. For older versions, you can take a look at [TraySaver](https://sourceforge.net/p/traysaver/wiki/Home/).

Officially the tray items are identified by hWnd + ID or GUID but it is possible that Windows cares about the process id and/or exe name as well. If this is the case, you would have to inject into the process.

You can use a debugger on said application and just set a breakpoint on shell32!Shell_NotifyIconW to figure out the ID used by the application you are interested in. The hIcon is not part of the identity.

I just tested and `NIM_DELETE` works just fine if you just know the HWND and ID (assuming it does not use a GUID).

In WinDbg, open the exe in question and do this to find the ID:

```
> bp shell32!Shell_NotifyIconW
> g
```

(keep using `g` until you are inside `Shell_NotifyIconW`)

```
> dd  poi(esp+8)+8 L2 ; .echo _________ ^ID      ^Flags
```

I ended up with

```
0018fba8  00000001 0000000f
_________ ^ID      ^Flags
```

Where 1 is the ID and Flags does not include 0x20 (GUID).

Comment: So what do I basically need to do for making the item disappear? I am working for my company who has it's background data receiver from users and there's an icon appearing which freaks them out. The source code is not in my hands and I have to found a way of deleteing the icon. I thought of executing a program that basically does the opposite of creating this icon, I thought about a disassembler but I think it's too far.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/customize-the-taskbar-notification-area-e159e8d2-9ac5-b2bd-61c5-bb63c1d437c3

Comment: What I mean by saying making the item icon disappear is basically removing it. I want it to run in the background but not being seen in the icon tray. I have the program running in multiple computers.